# Generating Unique and Sequential Transaction ID based on Year

Tags: php

I have an php application which generates a unique transaction ID. However, I discovered that at times, two transactions are having the same ID. Below is my code. I will appreciate if I can know the reason while it is given two transactions the same transid.Also, I want to the transid to be start counting from 1 at the beginning of a new year. I don't know how to go about that.

For Question 1:

```
<?php 
$db = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_requisition");
$nrw = mysqli_num_rows($db);
$refID= ("NR".date("Y").($nrw+1));?>
   <tr>
   <th>Requisition ID:</th>
  <td><input  type="text" name="refid" value="<?php echo $refID;?>"  size="100"  readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
```

For Question 2:
How can I make the $refID above to start counting from 1 at the beginning of each year. Like NR20161,NR20162.....NR20165000. Assuming at the end of 31/12/2016, the last id is NR20165000.I want the next one to start with NR20171,NR20172,......NR2017XXXXX

I will appreciate any response on how to prevent the duplicate above and resetting at the beginning of each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own table "NumberGroups" for that purpose with the following columns:

- Year: Integer
- NextNumber: Integer

with Primary Key on Year.

If you then want to get the next number for a year, use the following SQL query:

```
insert into NumberGroups(Year, NextNumber) values (2016, LAST_INSERT_ID(1) + 1) on duplicate key update NextNumber = LAST_INSERT_ID(NextNumber) + 1; 
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Execute this in one call to `mysqli_query()` replacing 2016 with the year you want the counter for. This will then return the next free number to use, starting with 1 for each year.

What it does:

It checks whether there already is a row for the given year in the table. 
If there is no row with the given year, a new row is inserted with the value 2 as NextNumber and LAST_INSERT_ID() is set to 1. 
If there is already a row with the given year, the existing row is updated and NextNumber for that row is increased by one, remembering the old value of NextNumber in LAST_INSERT_ID().
Lastly, the value we set in LAST_INSERT_ID() is returned to the caller.

The problem in your current approach is that when several actions run in parallel, two can read the same row count in your table. If you want unique counters you must make sure, no two activities running in parallel read the same value. You could do that by using transactions with the correct isolation level or you can do it (as in this variant) by reading the current value and incrementing it in one and the same SQL statement.

Resources:

- [Insert On Duplicate Key Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
- [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Please, is this solution for  Question 1 or 2. Because it seems it is for quest2. Please clearify. WIll this call be for the Transaction ID  or what?

Comment: This is for both questions. The SQL query will return one number that you can use to build the transaction ID.

Answer (score 2):

```
$nrw = mysqli_num_rows($db);
$refID= ("NR".date("Y").($nrw+1));?>
```

That's an absolute No No. What if you delete rows some day? Your next id will go down but it will be there already and that's the reason you are getting that error.

You can't use the row count to efficiently decide what should the next number be.

You can simply use Auto increment value for this and your RDBMS will take care of the collisions. You can then use that auto increment value to generate your Alphanumeric unique id.

Comment: You mean I should have created a field in my DB  that will be auto incremented or I manuallu auto increment it when a record is inserted into the DB.I already have id as auto increment in the DB which is invariably the Primary Key

Answer (score 1):

To add to Hanky Panky's answer.

**NOTE: Below code is not tested**

Add `year` column to database table (along side the auto incrementing unique ID),

When transaction actually takes place:

```
INSERT INTO `tab_requisition` (year, ...) VALUES(YEAR(NOW()), ...)
```

Capture REAL unique ID for the transaction / record

```
$ID = mysqli_insert_id ($db);
```

Get current year record count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab_requisition` WHERE `year` = YEAR(NOW()) 
-- below line should take care of raise condition (if another record was added meanwhile)
AND `id` <= '.$ID
```

Generate your Serial / Ref number

```
$prefix = 'NR';
$year = date('Y');
$count = str_pad($year_record_count,6,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$refNum = $year . $count;
```

Finally, update your record with your `refNum`:

```
UPDATE `tab_requisition` SET `ref_num` = "'.$refNum.'" WHERE id = '.$ID
```

`str_pad` is used to pad your count to a specific length, this will produce proper numbering for sorting etc.

Instead of

```
NR20171
NR20172
NR201712
NR2017137
```

it would become

```
NR2017000001
NR2017000002
NR2017000012
NR2017000137
```

I know, it takes several DB calls, but it could work for you, depending on server load / traffic

Comment: Pls understand that this trasactionID will be generated upon opening the page, which is readonly. How will I perform Insertion into the DB when the transaction  values are yet to be inserted into the row? Also, is it compulsory to add padding?

Comment: @Dave 1) I cannot see how one can have an ID of event / transaction that hasn't occur. What do you mean by 'transaction', a page load?
2) I think padding is just make sense, nothing is compulsory really, just the good practices.

Comment: The transactio ID I mean here is just a reference ID which is used to uniquely identify that row.So, I need to fetch it from the DB, which will be presented as Readonly on the form , expecting the user to fill other part of the form.After Successful filling, the Data is committed to the DB.