# PHP, Increment a number by 1 at the beginning of each year

Tags: php

My apologies for such an simple question, but I am new to PHP and cannot find a answer that is specific to my issue.

I have a variable:

```
$i = 15
```

At the beginning of each year on January 1, YEAR increment $i++

So basically on `January 1, 2019, 15` will click up to 16.

Thanks!

Comment: this is quite broad... are you looping through dates?

Comment: not clear what is being asked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Unique and Sequential Transaction ID based on Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575168/generating-unique-and-sequential-transaction-id-based-on-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can accomplish this task using the date("Y"); function in php which gives you the current year.

Initially you declare you variable and the yearStarted that could be 2018, 2019 etc.Then using date("Y"); you get the current year. You can then subtract that from the yearStarted which will give you number of years that have passed. Finally you can add that number of years to your initial variable to give you the desired result. For example I assumed I started in 2015 the value of $i is 1 now 3 years have passed so $i should be 1+3=4 which is the output of this program.

```
<?php
    // Declare your variable
    $i=1;
    //Declare the year you started this on
    $yearStarted=2015;
    //Using PHP date("Y") to get the current year
    $currentYear= date("Y");

    //Difference of years from current time to when started
    $yearDifference=$currentYear-$yearStarted;

    //Adding the difference of years to your main variable
    $i=$i+$yearDifference;

    // print/echo your variable
    echo $i;
    ?>
```

**Output**:

**4**

Comment: Thanks Usman! This is what I came up with:

<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

function addOrdinalNumberSuffix($num) {
    if (!in_array(($num % 100),array(11,12,13))){
      switch ($num % 10) {
        // Handle 1st, 2nd, 3rd
        case 1:  return $num.'st';
        case 2:  return $num.'nd';
        case 3:  return $num.'rd';
      }
    }
    return $num.'th';
  }

$current_date = date('Y'); 

//Persons Name
$persons_name = 1982;
$ys_name = $current_date - $persons_name;

echo $ys_name; echo "<br>";

Comment: No problem Jason.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly this is what you want:

```
if ( date('z') === '0' ) {
    //Today is the first day of the year.
    $i++;
}
```

Of course it must be you to decide where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Php Date Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date('Y');
//Which Automatically Incress As current year
```